# Any website with a list of thirdparty java libraries?

Tags: java

I'm wondering if there is a website with like a list of java libraries/jars where you can browse around and see if theres something you could use. like when you make your own program which then contains lots of useful stuff.

Sort of like a website where people share their code, for public use.

Comment: You can browse Maven Central. It's not exactly built for the purpose of discovery, but I can't think of anything more comprehensive. If I have a problem that I suspect someone has already written a library for, I just do a web search.

Comment: probably better to search for specific functionality you want to use.  But, I still like to search [github](https://www.github.com) just for fun

Comment: Ok, ill try have a look at the Maven Central, and github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/directory/language%3ajava/)
- [Freecode (Freshmeat)](http://freecode.com/tags/java)
- [Google Code](http://code.google.com/query/#q=java)
- [github](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=Java&q=java)
- [Java.net](http://www.java.net/projects/community)

Comment: I didnt know the freecode and java.net, and they seem roughly like what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

http://mvnrepository.com - if you know jar name or package name.  it will provide you available versions and pom/ivy/gradle coordinates for copy/paste.

http://findjar.com/ - helps you to find jar containing this f*%^ing class nobody knows about (and then you can search mvnrepository  to look if it is available for maven build - if not, the best is just ignore this  library as this is probably of low quality or not yet released to public properly)

Comment: This is very useful and i'll definitively save them as bookmarks, but since i was more looking for a browsing experience; i.e. looking through a list and then get inspired to use some code.